# Setup twitter fabric sdk for cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to use Twitter login in my app using cordova, and I haven't found any plugin allowing to perform native login using the installed Twitter app credential.

So i want to create my own plugin, but I'm stuck on how to [integrate Twitter sdk](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate) into my plugin.xml file.
According to twitter's documentation, i'm supposed to edit my build.gradle to include the Maven repository and apply Fabric

```
 buildscript {
  repositories {
   jcenter()
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
  }
 dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3'
  // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to
  // react quickly to Android tooling updates
  classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
 }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
 jcenter()
 maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}
```

My problem is, I have no idea how to do that in my plugin.xml file, and [cordova plugin documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html) doesn't talk about that.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of [Cordova v5.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) and [Cordova Android v4.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html) Gradle is replacing Ant as the default build system. Here are the changes you might find interesting:

> **Changes For Plugin Developers:**
>
> Build using Gradle
>
> - All builds use [Gradle by default](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html#Android%20Shell%20Tool%20Guide_building_with_gradle), instead of Ant
> - Plugins can add their own gradle build steps!
> - Plugins can depend on Maven libraries using  tags

So plugins can also include build-extras.gradle files via:

```
<framework src="some.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on making a plugin as well. You can view the plugin's [progress here](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/twitter-connect-plugin). It still has rough edges as the gradle.build file needs dependencies and I don't know of a way to inject them correctly.

I've successfully used it in a simple "Hello Cordova" app and am working on trying to get it to work in a company project.